# Company Name In Username

Tags: discussion

I've checked the other [self](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1376/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion-on-server-fault) [promotion](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/592/etiquette-for-blatent-product-pushers) threads and they weren't directly on topic to my question.

[This User](https://serverfault.com/users/102770/paul-ackerman-vaccinet-llc) seems to have named his account to promote his sideline SMB IT business (and his bio reads to me like a tout sheet/cover letter).  It seems a bit gauche to me.  Am I just too sensitive on this or does it go beyond the promotion guidelines?

Comment: Just about to post this =) No I don't think this should be allowed, self promotion is OK in bios but not usernames, in my view

Comment: I don't think there are any restrictions on usernames. If you go searching there are quite a few people who do this or similar.

Comment: Well, he pulled out the company name, so that's something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The greater Stack Exchange community has agreed that such names are to be allowed.

[Are user names that represent domains allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100860/are-user-names-that-represent-domains-allowed)

The accepted answer on that one is what the SE policy is on this topic.

> The identity you choose is a personal thing. If someone wanted to be called (for example) "Ubuntu Fanboi", we wouldn't be having this conversation. So is a username like "AskUbuntu.com" really all that different? It's not indiscriminate advertising... it's a username; and it's not a part of the *information content* of this site. In short, **there is no "spam" to a username**.

https://serverfault.com/users/1581/robert-cartaino

Comment: I was looking for that and couldn't find it. My mSO-fu is rubbish.

Comment: @Iain I cheated. I asked some of the MSO mods.

Answer (score 6):

I actually think this is much better than the ones who try to hide it.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I don't see any problem with the username. It's pretty clear that his name is in there, and a related company name. The name itself does not "promote" the company. If his username was "You should hire Acme Co" that'd be different.

His BIO is definitely within what's allowed. It's his place to brag about his accomplishments and undertakings. If those read out as a CV/Resume/Blatant pleading for employment, then so be it. There's no mandate in the general use of the site to ever see that.

I have not seen the content of his answers, but they would be of the most concern to me. If he is constantly promoting himself or his business then that situation is clearly addressed in the [FAQ]. If his answers have no mention of his business or available services then he's contributing to the community and that can't be wrong.

**Update**:
Just looked over several of their posts, no mention at all of the company or availability of employment. Looks like their on the up and up to me.

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted a couple of of his answers w/out noticing the username, so I'd say it's ok.  Looking at the account now, it seems overly self-promoting to include the company name, but I don't think it's any worse than allowing "OMG Ponies!" or other silly usernames.

Comment: Um... There's nothing silly about "OMG Ponies" as a username. You take that back!

Answer (score -8):

I agree with you, I'll have a word with them.

Comment: Please don't. Users are allowed to have [almost anything](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) in their profile, provided it isn't patently offensive or breaking the law. The line is crossed when the user starts making spam posts.